# Scitools3 gives a module not found from import statement

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, scitools

According to https://pypi.org/project/scitools3/ importing the module as `from scitools.std import *` should work, but it gives me an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scitools.std'`. I've looked everywhere for a solution and can't find a fix